# MVC 5 Owin application cookie shared between two projects running from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

So I have a solution with two MVC5 Web Applications, both using Owin authentication.
When I run both applications at the same time through Visual Studio 2015, the owin context is shared (which it should not be!)

By shared, I mean that whenever I add a claim to one of the applications, it's also added to the other. This results in the `User.Identity.GetUserId()` returning the UserId from which ever application I logged into last, even though the 2 applications has nothing to do with each other, and has no references between each other.

I use the default Owin settings:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
```

Can someone help me configure my apps, so that they don't share the application cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [CookieName in CookieAuthenticationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.cookiename(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieName)

> Determines the cookie name used to persist the identity. The default value is ".AspNet.Cookies". This value should be changed if you change the name of the AuthenticationType, especially if your system uses the cookie authentication middleware multiple times.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "AspNet.AppName"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the setting I was looking for, and it works.